# appending characters to end of specific lines in a multifasta file

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

I have a multifasta file with paired-end reads such that those adjacent to each other are mates (they have the same read name). I want to append "/1" and "/2" to the first and second read, respectively, throughout the file. I do not know how many reads are in the file. Here is how the file looks like(adding blank lines between reads for clarity):

> HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0
>   ACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTT
>   CCCATTCCCCTAGGGCTGAGACCCAATATCCTCTATCCCTG
>
> HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0
>   GTGCAGGCATGTTGGGGCGTGTCTCAGAGCCTGAACTTCCCTTCCAGTCAGTGCTGGAAG
>   GAGGTGGGCAGGGGAATGATAGAAAGGAAGGAGTGGATTGG
>
> HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0
>   ACAGCTATACACGAAGAATCTCAGCCCTTGTACTTTTGCATAGTCTCATACACGTATCAG
>   AAGCCTCCACCTGGCTAACAGGAATTTGGGGCTTTGGGAGA
>
> HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0
>   TTTGGGAGATTTTTTAATCAGGGCAAAACCTGTACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTC
>   CTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCC

And this is how I want it to appear:

> HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0/1
>   ACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTT
>   CCCATTCCCCTAGGGCTGAGACCCAATATCCTCTATCCCTG
>
> HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0/2
>   GTGCAGGCATGTTGGGGCGTGTCTCAGAGCCTGAACTTCCCTTCCAGTCAGTGCTGGAAG
>   GAGGTGGGCAGGGGAATGATAGAAAGGAAGGAGTGGATTGG
>
> HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0/1
>   ACAGCTATACACGAAGAATCTCAGCCCTTGTACTTTTGCATAGTCTCATACACGTATCAG
>   AAGCCTCCACCTGGCTAACAGGAATTTGGGGCTTTGGGAGA
>
> HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0/2
>   TTTGGGAGATTTTTTAATCAGGGCAAAACCTGTACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTC
>   CTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCC

I will then grep it, remove the "--" separator and save the forward reads (i.e.,those ending in "/1") and the reverse reads (i.e., those ending in "/2") in different files as follows:

```
grep -A 2 "/1" filename.fa | sed '/--/d' > reads_1.fa
grep -A 2 "/2" filename.fa | sed '/--/d' > reads_2.fa
```

I think this can be done with sed and awk but I haven't yet figured out how. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1}{if($0~/#0/){print $0"/"i;if(i==1)i=2;else i=1;}else {print}}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
>HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0
ACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTT
CCCATTCCCCTAGGGCTGAGACCCAATATCCTCTATCCCTG
>HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0
GTGCAGGCATGTTGGGGCGTGTCTCAGAGCCTGAACTTCCCTTCCAGTCAGTGCTGGAAG
GAGGTGGGCAGGGGAATGATAGAAAGGAAGGAGTGGATTGG
>HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0
ACAGCTATACACGAAGAATCTCAGCCCTTGTACTTTTGCATAGTCTCATACACGTATCAG
AAGCCTCCACCTGGCTAACAGGAATTTGGGGCTTTGGGAGA
>HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0
TTTGGGAGATTTTTTAATCAGGGCAAAACCTGTACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTC
CTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCC
```

execution:

```
> awk 'BEGIN{i=1}{if($0~/#0/){print $0"/"i;if(i==1)i=2;else i=1;}else {print}}' temp
>HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0/1
ACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTT
CCCATTCCCCTAGGGCTGAGACCCAATATCCTCTATCCCTG
>HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0/2
GTGCAGGCATGTTGGGGCGTGTCTCAGAGCCTGAACTTCCCTTCCAGTCAGTGCTGGAAG
GAGGTGGGCAGGGGAATGATAGAAAGGAAGGAGTGGATTGG
>HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0/1
ACAGCTATACACGAAGAATCTCAGCCCTTGTACTTTTGCATAGTCTCATACACGTATCAG
AAGCCTCCACCTGGCTAACAGGAATTTGGGGCTTTGGGAGA
>HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0/2
TTTGGGAGATTTTTTAATCAGGGCAAAACCTGTACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTC
CTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCC
>
```

Comment: I found this easier to understand than the one by @Kent but both work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using sed to generate the intermediate file:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

1 {
    x
    s/^$/\\1/
    x
}
/^HWI/ {
    G
    s/\n//
    x
    y/12/21/
    x
}
```

In a single line:

```
sed -e '1{x;s/^$/\\1/;x};/^HWI/{G;s/\n//;x;y/12/21/;x}'
```

The commands are quite simple. The commands grouped in the first pair of braces are executed for the first line, and they initialize the hold space (an auxiliary buffer) with `\1`. To do this, we swap the contents of the pattern space (working buffer) with that of the hold space with the `x` exchange command. Then we replace an empty line with `\1`, and then swap the spaces again.

The commands grouped in the second pair of braces are executed for every line that starts with `HWI`. First we append the contents of the hold space into the pattern space. Because it is appended starting with a newline character, the next command removes it. Now we have to swap the number from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 1. First we swap the contents of the spaces again, and then use the `y` command to swap characters. It defines that when a 1 or a 2 is found, they must be replaced with a 2 or a 1, respectively. Finally, we restore the contents of the spaces.

You can also write a single script to do everything, separating them into the files:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

/^HWI/! d

:start_forward
s/$/\\1/

:forward
w reads_1.fa
n
/^HWI/! b forward

s/$/\\2/

:reverse
w reads_2.fa
n
/^HWI/! b reverse

b start_forward
```

In a shorter form:

```
sed -e '/^HWI/!d;:s;s/$/\\1/;:f;wreads_1.fa
    n;/^HWI/!bf;s/$/\\2/;:r;wreads_2.fa
    n;/^HWI/!br;bs'
```

Here we start by ignoring all lines until we find a line that starts with `HWI`. Then we have to loops, one for writing the forward data and another for the backward data. Between the loops there are commands for appending the respective `\1` or `\2` before writing the line to the respective file. The loops are analogous, they simple write the line to their respective file, load a new line from the input and check if it is a line starting with `HWI`, indicating that it should go to the next loop.

A more thorough explanation:

The first command is executed when the line doesn't start with `HWI` (we negate the match by adding a `!` right after it). The command is `d` to delete a line, and also force sed to load the next line and restart the script. Effectively, we loop until we find a string that starts with `HWI`.

Now, we use the `:` command to define a label called `start_forward`. A label is nothing more than an name to a location in the script to where we can jump to. If we keep jumping between labels and never reach the end of the script, we'll end up never restarting the script, so the first command never gets executed after the first line that starts with `HWI` is found. The first thing we do is append the `\1` to the end of the line.

Now we define a new label, called `forward` which will be used to jump back when we loop through the lines. The loop is quite simple, first we write the current line to the respective file `reads_1.fa` using the `w` command, then we use the `n` line to read the next line into pattern space, and finally we check if the newly read line start with `HWI`. If it doesn't, we execute the `b` branch command to jump back to the `forward` label, allowing us to start another iteration of the loop.

If the lines does start with `HWI`, we now must go to the other loop. Before though, we must append the line with `\2`. The loop is analogous to the previous one, except that when we exit the loop when another `HWI` line is found, we must branch back to the `start_forward` label with the `b` command in order to switch back to the previous loop.

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 1):

This adds `/0` and `/1` to the reads:

```
perl -pe 'if (/#0/) { $x = 1 - $x; s:#0:#0/$x: }'
```

Comment: I preferred the awk solutions because I am trying to improve my "awk-fu". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

awk one-liner:

```
 awk -F'#' 'NF==2{a[$1]=($1 in a)?++a[$1]:1;$0=$0"/"a[$1];}1' file
```

**test**

```
kent$  cat t.txt
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0
ACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTT 
CCCATTCCCCTAGGGCTGAGACCCAATATCCTCTATCCCTG

HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0
GTGCAGGCATGTTGGGGCGTGTCTCAGAGCCTGAACTTCCCTTCCAGTCAGTGCTGGAAG 
GAGGTGGGCAGGGGAATGATAGAAAGGAAGGAGTGGATTGG

HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0
ACAGCTATACACGAAGAATCTCAGCCCTTGTACTTTTGCATAGTCTCATACACGTATCAG 
AAGCCTCCACCTGGCTAACAGGAATTTGGGGCTTTGGGAGA

HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0
TTTGGGAGATTTTTTAATCAGGGCAAAACCTGTACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTC 
CTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCC

kent$  awk -F'#' 'NF==2{a[$1]=($1 in a)?++a[$1]:1;$0=$0"/"a[$1];}1' t.txt
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0/1
ACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTT 
CCCATTCCCCTAGGGCTGAGACCCAATATCCTCTATCCCTG

HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0/2
GTGCAGGCATGTTGGGGCGTGTCTCAGAGCCTGAACTTCCCTTCCAGTCAGTGCTGGAAG 
GAGGTGGGCAGGGGAATGATAGAAAGGAAGGAGTGGATTGG

HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0/1
ACAGCTATACACGAAGAATCTCAGCCCTTGTACTTTTGCATAGTCTCATACACGTATCAG 
AAGCCTCCACCTGGCTAACAGGAATTTGGGGCTTTGGGAGA

HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0/2
TTTGGGAGATTTTTTAATCAGGGCAAAACCTGTACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTC 
CTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCC
```

Answer (score 1):

You have what's called a shuffled multifasta. You can use `GNU awk` to unshuffle it and create two files. Note that there's no need to use `grep` or `sed` to perform any post-processing. This code will create two files for you:

```
awk 'NR%4==1 { getline one; printf "%s/1\n%s\n", $0, one > "reads_1.fa" } NR%4==3 { getline two; printf "%s/2\n%s\n", $0, two > "reads_2.fa" }' file.txt
```

**Input:**

```
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0
ACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCCCCTAGGGCTGAGACCCAATATCCTCTATCCCTG
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0
GTGCAGGCATGTTGGGGCGTGTCTCAGAGCCTGAACTTCCCTTCCAGTCAGTGCTGGAAGGAGGTGGGCAGGGGAATGATAGAAAGGAAGGAGTGGATTGG
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0
ACAGCTATACACGAAGAATCTCAGCCCTTGTACTTTTGCATAGTCTCATACACGTATCAGAAGCCTCCACCTGGCTAACAGGAATTTGGGGCTTTGGGAGA
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0
TTTGGGAGATTTTTTAATCAGGGCAAAACCTGTACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCC
```

**Results:**

Contents of `reads_1.fa`:

```
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0/1
ACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCCCCTAGGGCTGAGACCCAATATCCTCTATCCCTG
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0/1
ACAGCTATACACGAAGAATCTCAGCCCTTGTACTTTTGCATAGTCTCATACACGTATCAGAAGCCTCCACCTGGCTAACAGGAATTTGGGGCTTTGGGAGA
```

Contents of `reads_2.fa`:

```
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0/2
GTGCAGGCATGTTGGGGCGTGTCTCAGAGCCTGAACTTCCCTTCCAGTCAGTGCTGGAAGGAGGTGGGCAGGGGAATGATAGAAAGGAAGGAGTGGATTGG
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0/2
TTTGGGAGATTTTTTAATCAGGGCAAAACCTGTACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCC
```

Comment: You didn't test your code otherwise you would have realized that it adds "/1" even to the sequence!

Comment: @TjbLaMac: I used an actual shuffled fasta, like the one you describe without the empty lines you added for 'clarity'. Code has been tested.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{if(NR<3){sub(/#0/,"#0/"NR);print $0,"\n"}else{NR=1;sub(/#0/,"#0/"NR);print $0,"\n"}}' file
```

Result:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}{if(NR<3){sub(/#0/,"#0/"NR); print $0,"\n"}else{NR=1;sub(/#0/,"#0/"NR);print $0, "\n"}}' file 
HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0/1 
ACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTCCTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTT 
CCCATTCCCCTAGGGCTGAGACCCAATATCCTCTATCCCTG 

HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10007:34134#0/2 
GTGCAGGCATGTTGGGGCGTGTCTCAGAGCCTGAACTTCCCTTCCAGTCAGTGCTGGAAG 
GAGGTGGGCAGGGGAATGATAGAAAGGAAGGAGTGGATTGG 

HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0/1 
ACAGCTATACACGAAGAATCTCAGCCCTTGTACTTTTGCATAGTCTCATACACGTATCAG 
AAGCCTCCACCTGGCTAACAGGAATTTGGGGCTTTGGGAGA 

HWI-ST1018:1:1101:10016:6488#0/2 
TTTGGGAGATTTTTTAATCAGGGCAAAACCTGTACTAGTAACCACATGTCCAGACTCCTC 
CTATGCTCCCACCCAGGGTCCCTTGAGCTGCTTCCCATTCC
```